# Proof that logistic map doesn't have closed form solution?

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

I've read in various places that the well-known recurrence equation $x_{n+1}=\alpha x_n(1-x_n)$ doesn't have a closed form solution, except for a few specific values of $\alpha$ like $-2$, $2$, and $4$.  I wasn't able to find a proof for this, though, i.e. a proof for the fact that there's no general closed form solution.  Could someone please tell me where to look (books or papers)?

Comment: Typically what one is interested in is the location (if there are any) of points of particular least period eg $f_{3}=f_0$ means $f_0$ is a point of least period 3. But $f_{3}$ is a degree-6 polynomial in $f_0$, so in general one can’t solve for its roots in closed form (Abel’s theorem). The situation is progressively worse as you go up in degree. So there’s no hope to get such cycles analytically.